# Completely remove Ubuntu and partitions from Mac OS X Lion

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, mac

I couldn't make the WiFi work on Ubuntu 12 after installing alongside OS X for a try. I tried everything and nothing worked, now I'd like to completely remove it since it's too complicated, is it safe to just remove the partitions it created?

Comment: I started Ubuntu a month or two ago and thought it was really confusing at first. I had a similar issue of the wifi not working and also had issues installing. However, after solving those issues, it turns out I really like Ubuntu. Try posting your wifi question here and we'll see if anyone can give you a hand. If you do decide to post the question, make sure to include *every* solution you've already solved so we can get to the bottom of your issue quickly and successfully.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu This is a different question. [There](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142179/how-do-i-completely-remove-ubuntu-12-04-on-my-mac), the OP wanted to remove Ubuntu with the intention of putting back a different version of Ubuntu shortly thereafter. In this question, the intention is to remove Ubuntu without planning to reinstall it. So an answer to *this* question should explain how to re-expand the OS X partition (something [my answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/142180/22949)) explicitly does not do. Also, an answer *here* would not have to explain how to install Ubuntu back.