# Unable to remove/uninstall Ubuntu from a MacBook

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, macbook

I recently received an old MacBook from my brother. He had installed some version of Ubuntu on it. I haven't been able to use it since it's completely foreign to me. Therefore, I decided to uninstall it. The problem is; it doesn't seem to be away to reach the bios on start-up. Something called Yaboot appears on screen and I have no clue what to do with that. I am all set up to install a new is but this has stopped me. I'm very new to Ubuntu as I have no experience using it. Kindly explain as to what I should do with basic explanations. Also, please advise me if any further information needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check these pages:

- [Erase Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Erase-Ubuntu)
- [I want to uninstall Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243910/i-want-to-uninstall-ubuntu?rq=1)
- [How do I completely remove Ubuntu 12.04 on my Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142179/how-do-i-completely-remove-ubuntu-12-04-on-my-mac)

Hopefully works...

Comment: This didn't help sadly. All those methods depend on accessing the bios so I could boot from my recovery disk. I have no clue how to. I've tried f2 but no option ever appears to access the bios

Comment: sorry. i am very new too. try searching on google.